# Reading from a file with fopen: is a char** returned correctly?

Tags: c, char, fgets

I have a problem with the getting correct data in a char* content. I want to read from file its content, fill my buffer with it, and be able to deference char** content to the address of buffer. And then get its data from char* content in main... What am I doing wrong so far?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void load(FILE* file, char** content, size_t* length);

int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    char* content;
    size_t length = 0;

    load(file, &content, &length);

    printf("%s\n", content);
    printf("%lu\n", length);
}

void load(FILE* file, char** content, size_t* length)
{
    char buffer[30];

       fgets(buffer, 30, file);
       *content = buffer;
       *length = strlen(buffer);

}
```

Comment: You `buffer[30]` gets destroyed upon returning from `load(....)`

Comment: You should allocate an area in dynamically allocated memory (e.g. using [malloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and read the file content into that memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your load function should look something like this:

```
void load(FILE* file, char** content, size_t* length)
{
    char *buffer;
    buffer = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));

       fgets(buffer, 30, file);
       *content = buffer;
       *length = strlen(buffer);

}
```

Comment: Do *NOT* cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) for thorough explanation.

Comment: Don't forget to `free` the memory in the other function, though.